Where to store versions of a project in Gitlab
Currently working on a gitlab pipeline project. The project itself will build artefacts and can't be done from gitlab. The orchestration however of the artefacts I can handle.
I can't use the out of the box solution of gitlab of generating a versionnumber. I need to create a version manually and store this somehow in GitLab where I can use the value in the pipeline.
Any ideas how this can be achieved?
Best
DJ
